# Fourier inversion formula with truncation

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and denote $$s_N(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-N}^N\hat{f}(t)e^{ixt}dt.$$ Show that $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_\mathbb{R}|s_N(x)-f(x)|^2dx=0$$

So, $s_N(x)$ is the truncation of the Fourier inversion Formula, and we want to show that it converges (in $L^2$ norm) to $f$. How to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $\hat{s}_N=1_{[-N,N]}\hat{f}$ (where $1_{[-N,N]}$ denotes the characteristic function of $[-N,N]$) so that by Plancherel

$$
\| s_N -f\|_{L^2} = \| \widehat{s_N-f}\|_{L^2} = \| \hat{f}(1-1_{[-N,N]})\|_{L^2}
$$

which clearly tends to $0$ with $N$.